# Fast ways to compute the smallest prime with a given substring?

Tags: algorithms, strings, primes

So, I've got this problem:

> Given a string $\omega\in\{0,\ldots,9\}^*$, find the smallest prime number (in base 10) that contains that string, or otherwise returns 0.

What I'm asking is a fast algorithm for the problem?

Comment: Okay, the problem is clear now. But what have you tried? So far, this is a dump of a problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion.

Comment: Every string should be contained in some prime. That should follow from the prime number theorem. To find the very first prime containing it, I'm not sure there is anything smarter than just going over all of them in sequence.

Comment: Is this going to be a practical algorithm (I guess so because you were talking about a C++ implementation)? If so, you should mention what additional constraints you might have.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Maybe, if we fix $\omega$ as the most significant bits, it's possible to pad with less significant bits in a structured way so the result is prime? I don't know enough about number theory to have an informed intuition.

Comment: An idea for a very fast practical implementation: precompute and store every prime up to a certain limit. Mark the indices of the first prime with $2, 3, \ldots, N$ digits. Given $\omega$, start going through the array from the first prime with at least $\omega$ digits. If you know something further about your queries or $\omega$, you can optimize this approach further.

Comment: @Raphael Right, that's the idea. The prime number theorem with error term gives you an estimate for the number of primes in an interval. If this estimate is positive, then there is some prime number in the interval. By padding with enough low-order digits, you can guarantee there to be lots of primes with the given high-order digits.

Comment: You could just try adding digits before and after and use a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Answer (score 1):

This answer only shows that every string actually appears in some prime. Without loss of generality, $\omega$ doesn't start with zero (otherwise, consider $1\omega$ instead). Consider all digits in the range $\omega \times 10^N$ to $\omega \times 10^N + 9 (10^{N-1} + \cdots + 10^0)$, an interval of length $10^N$. Let $M = \omega \times 10^N$. According to the prime number theorem, there are roughly $(M+10^N)/\log M - M/\log M \approx 10^N/\log M$ prime numbers in this interval. Since $10^N/\log M \to \infty$, for large enough $M$ there will be a prime number in the interval, and its most significant digits would be exactly $\omega$.

I don't expect there to be an algorithm much faster than going over all primes in sequence. If you *expect* the answer to be one of the first few primes (here *few* can be a rather large number, say $10^9$), then you can probably do some preprocessing to be able to handle such queries fast.